# Grouped UITableView shows weird square border

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder, ios-3.x

I am having a weird issue with a grouped `UITableView`. It shows a square border only on one of the views in the app, and only on the terminal that has iOS 3.1.3. Here you have an screenshot of the thing:

[image]

I am setting it up only through the `Interface Builder`, here are the settings:

[image]

The rest of the table views that are similarly set up in the app work just fine.

Does anyone have a clue about what might be causing this?

EDIT:

Setting the background color to clear color caused this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem troubled me too. I too asked [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779970/uitableviewcell-clear-background-grouped-uitableview) question on bStackOverflow. Check it out. It is the right solution.

Comment: I guess that works for iPad but i am getting the bug on iOS 3.1.3, whose `UITableViewCell` doesn't have the `backgroundView` property.

Answer (score 0):

in `viewwillAppear` method of your class set the `backgroundcolor` of your `tableview` as `clearcolor` like this

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

or in the xib file in view section of the table set the background property as clear color.